# How to load another file's content to the current file in Vim?

Tags: vim

As title, any convenient way?

I especially need it for some cvs/git commit or sendmail to load a template comment. I think it is a vi environment, not Vim.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

at the VIM command prompt:

```
:read new_file
```

or for short:

```
:r new_file
```

This will insert the contents of `new_file` under where the cursor is.  For instance if this is the contents of `new_file`:

```
I do not like green eggs and ham 
I do not like you sam I am
```

And this is the text you're editing:

```
I meant what I said and I said what I meant
An elephant's faithful one hundred percent.
```

And your cursor is on the first line and you type:

```
:read new_file
```

Then your buffer will be:

```
I meant what I said and I said what I meant
I do not like green eggs and ham 
I do not like you sam I am
An elephant's faithful one hundred percent.
```

Comment: As a side note, combined with ! you can also read the output of a command into vim. :r !ls

Comment: Is there a way to read the file without breaking up the current file's text ? Current file is 1 column of 10 numbers. Read-in file is 1 column of 10 numbers. I want current file to have the read-in file's column directly beside the column it already has.

Comment: @user1271772: I can't think of any way to do that off the top of my head.

Comment: @user1271772 this is much after the fact, but you might want to use the bash utility `paste` for that function rather than vim

Comment: @MicahSmith: Thank you, do you have an example? I'm not familiar with "bash utility" and "paste". I just want to read in a file and have the text placed beside the existing column, rather than underneath it.

Comment: @user1271772 If you have one column of text each in `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, running `paste file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt` from a *nix shell will place the results in `file3.txt`. Alternately, in vim, you could use visual block mode (C-v) to select a column of text, and it could then be pasted in your first file.

Comment: @MicahSmith, paste worked! Your vim solution doesn't work because visual block's cut/copy and paste features only work within a single file.