# Adding line numbers in vi and concatenating files in vi

Tags: unix, vi

How do I concatenate files 3 files in vi with a blank line after every file's content?
Also :set number does not save changes. I want to set numbers permanently for a file. How can I do that?

Comment: (1) see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169805/1462295 (2) add `set number` to vimrc (3) try asking on https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you use a `vi` that is not `vim` you might have to use `.exrc` instead of vimrc. If you don't insist on using `vi` to concatenate 3 files, you could use something like `( cat file1; echo; cat file2; echo ; cat file3` ) > outputfile` or `first=1; for file in file* ; do [ $first -ne 0 ] && echo ; first=0; cat "$file"; done > outputfile`

Comment: make a script that shows the three files with newlines and call `:r !scriptname`

Answer (score 0):

Look for a commandline option and use that. `cat -n` adds numbers, when you like that format, and you are editing a file that has been saved, use

```
:% !cat -n %
```